# How to get the combination table in Google Ads through api?

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to fetch ad group performance report with two demographics, `gender` and `age_range`, also with other metrics. So I used [gender_view](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v7/gender_view) with query body below, but found the information of `age_range` are all "UNSPECIFIED". By the way, [age_range_view](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v7/age_range_view) is the same result which the information of `gender` are all "UNSPECIFIED".

```
SELECT
    segments.date,
    campaign.name,
    ad_group.name,
    ad_group_criterion.criterion_id,
    ad_group_criterion.age_range.type,
    ad_group_criterion.gender.type,
    metrics.impressions,
    metrics.clicks,
    metrics.cost_micros, 
    metrics.conversions

FROM age_range_view WHERE segments.date BETWEEN "2021-01-01" AND "2021-04-30"
```

Is there any good method to query?